# How to remove specific subnets from variable via powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a powercli script like below. My question is : I want to remove IP Subnets such as  172.25.X.X , 169.X.X.X , 20.X.X.X. As Summary , I want to get an output  my desired output.

Here is my PowerCLI script:

```
$VMs = get-folder -name DR | get-vm

$VMs.extensiondata.guest | Where-Object {$_.GuestFullName -like "Microsoft*"} | Select-Object HostName,@{N='IP';E={[string]::Join(',',($_.Net | %{$_.IpAddress | where{$_.Split('.').Count -eq 4} | %{$_}}))}},GuestFullName | Export-Csv C:\report.csv -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

My sample output:

```
"HostName","IP","GuestFullName"
"srv01.contoso.local","10.22.23.90,172.25.55.12","Microsoft Windows Server 2016 or later (64-bit)"
"srv02.contoso.local","10.23.54.95","Microsoft Windows Server 2019 (64-bit)"
"srv03.contoso.local","10.11.54.211,172.25.100.200,169.254.42.164","Microsoft Windows Server 2019 (64-bit)"
"srv4.contoso.local","172.25.101.159,10.10.10.20,20.20.20.2","Microsoft Windows Server 2012 (64-bit)"
```

My desired output:

```
"HostName","IP","GuestFullName"
"srv01.contoso.local","10.22.23.90","Microsoft Windows Server 2016 or later (64-bit)"
"srv02.contoso.local","10.23.54.95","Microsoft Windows Server 2019 (64-bit)"
"srv03.contoso.local","10.11.54.211","Microsoft Windows Server 2019 (64-bit)"
"srv4.contoso.local","10.10.10.20","Microsoft Windows Server 2012 (64-bit)"
```

Comment: Too bad it's not json where arrays are supported.

Comment: I suggest you remove "such as" because the reader has no idea how your examples should be generalized.

Comment: I think it would be easier to do and say "keep only 10.x.x.x" instead of excluding multiple others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple regex to achieve your purpose:

```
^(?!172\.25|169|20)(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}$
```

**Explanation of above regex:**

- `^` - Asserts start of line.
- `(?!172\.25|169|20)` - Represents a negative lookahead which asserts that the string should not be matched if it starts with `172.25`, `169` or `20`.
- `(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}` - Non-capturing group which matches digits upto 3 length and the complete patterns repeats 3 times.
- `\d{1,3}` - Matches digits only between 1 to 3.
- `$` - Asserts end of line.

*[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/JWngNz/2)*

[image: Image regex]

```bash
$VMs = get-folder -name DR | get-vm

$VMs.extensiondata.guest | Where-Object {$_.GuestFullName -like "Microsoft*"} | Select-Object HostName,@{N='IP';E={[string]::Join(',',($_.Net | %{$_.IpAddress | where{($_ -match '^(?!172\.25|169|20)(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}$')}}))}},GuestFullName | Export-Csv C:\report.csv -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

***[CMDLET DEMO](https://tio.run/##fVDBaoNAEL3vV0yNkATqsrtqioWSlEJLTpX20Is0GB1xi1FZFxqI@Xa7bkmKl8IwzPDevHkzbfONqiuxqoaNQzijQlDh04gRfmeqkIYh5cICPg0DGoVjzflYC84vLM4MgZmhVWTagAaC8lXwh3LKw8hO2hCMiDHbIM4GenhH7T01tcZagyPbXZrnCrsOO6qP2hlm8IZpDtsYrgAUqjmALhE0HjUUskLiyvbxij/Ay7@ihMzgWVYa1VR3n3aYQ1Nb7UxJQ5ApcQtLxXwbj9KTTT18lAbyXvdfmGk4uTvwDqnOSph/LtY35g2J@UNvvtMLtlys75P8xG/9c0KXJ5N/G3d@Hh3FStb2Grts4mziYRh@AA)***

Comment: thanks you very much. it works very well.

Comment: @Arbelac welcome:) I have shortened the regex. You can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could use a regex pattern and `-notmatch` to filter out those IPs starting with `172.25.`, `169.`, `20.`.

```bash
$VMs.extensiondata.guest | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.GuestFullName -notlike 'Microsoft*') {
        return
    }

    $ips = @($_.Net.IpAddress) -notmatch '^(?:172\.25\.|169\.|20\.|:)'

    [pscustomobject]@{
        HostName      = $_.HostName
        IP            = $ips -join ','
        GuestFullName = $_.GuestFullName
    }
} | Export-Csv C:\report.csv -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

Comment: I am assuming, your script is not working. I am getting ipV6 output such as fe80::97de:7a96:ff7d:9e76,10.110.224.41,fe80::2b10:3cbf:409a:4783

Comment: 10.110.2.41
172.25.111.210
fe80::97de:7a96:ff7d:9e76
fe80::2b10:3cbf:409a:4783   , Normally,  I need to get `10.110.2.41`

Comment: I didn't think you could get ipv6 addresses there, adding `:` to the regex pattern would also avoid those

Answer (score 1):

This is longer but pretty simple to understand.  Split the comma seperated networks into an array and filter.  You could have done this in the first place before exporting to csv.

```
$csv = import-csv file.csv
$csv = $csv | % { $_.ip = $_.ip -split ','; $_ }
$csv = $csv | % { $_.ip = $_.ip | ? { 
  $_ -notlike '172.25.*.*' -and 
  $_ -notlike '169.*.*.*' -and 
  $_ -notlike '20.*.*.*' }; $_ }
$csv

HostName            IP           GuestFullName
--------            --           -------------
srv01.contoso.local 10.22.23.90  Microsoft Windows Server 2016 or later (64-bit)
srv02.contoso.local 10.23.54.95  Microsoft Windows Server 2019 (64-bit)
srv03.contoso.local 10.11.54.211 Microsoft Windows Server 2019 (64-bit)
srv4.contoso.local  10.10.10.20  Microsoft Windows Server 2012 (64-bit)
```

If the input file were json, the ip property would already be an array, and not need the split.

```
[   {   "HostName":  "srv01.contoso.local",
        "IP":  ["10.22.23.90","172.25.55.12"],
        "GuestFullName":  "Microsoft Windows Server 2016 or later (64-bit)"
    },
    {   "HostName":  "srv02.contoso.local",
        "IP":  ["10.23.54.95"],
        "GuestFullName":  "Microsoft Windows Server 2019 (64-bit)"
    },
    {   "HostName":  "srv03.contoso.local",
        "IP":  ["10.11.54.211","172.25.100.200","169.254.42.164"],
        "GuestFullName":  "Microsoft Windows Server 2019 (64-bit)"
    },
    {   "HostName":  "srv4.contoso.local",
        "IP":  ["172.25.101.159","10.10.10.20","20.20.20.2"],
        "GuestFullName":  "Microsoft Windows Server 2012 (64-bit)"
    }
]
```